# Unable to Add React to existing Rails app

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpacker, react-rails

I've setup a rails app all good, server runs fine etc, now I need to add React to it.
I see the command

```
rails webpack:install:react
```

appears to be the way everyone recommends but when I run this I get the following error:

```
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'webpacker:install:react' (See the list of available 
tasks with `rails --tasks`)
Did you mean?  webpacker:install
```

So I run `webpacker:install`, alls good then try with `:react` again and the same errors generated, I've got react added in the package.json file and react-rails in the gem file. I've also run bundled since adding these.

I cant find an answer anywhere so whatever you've got I'll take.

Thank you.

Comment: `bundle install` and then `rails webpacker:install:react`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the problem was that webpacker:install:react was removed from webpacker v6, moved to version 5.4.3 and the issues resolved.
More info here:
https://github.com/rails/webpacker/pull/2802/files#diff-8efe491b392a5a50e31b54660bbc0e7258e544e36d4e0b8a65e4cca93d39d18c

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer states, this was removed. If you see a tutorial telling you to run `rails webpack:install:react` you can simply skip it if you've already run `rails webpack:install`. React now works "out of the box" and so you don't need to specify it.